# TypeError: must be str, not datetime.date when trying to create a file in Python

Tags: python, file, date

I am trying to generate a text file that looks like this:

**config_18092019_123456.txt**

So I thought this line in Python will do it:

```
file = open("config_" + today + "_" + choosen_asn + ".txt","w+", encoding='utf-8')
```

But I get following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wes-prefix.py", line 15, in <module>
    file = open("config_" + today + "_" + choosen_asn,"w+", encoding='utf-8')
TypeError: must be str, not datetime.date
```

The variable **today** looks like this:

```
today = date.today()
```

How do I fix this? How do I get the current date as string?

Comment: If you echoed today, what value does it prints. Have you tried ```today = str(date.today())```?

Comment: I did `date.today`. I tried to add `date.today()` instead and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like below.

```
from datetime import datetime
today = str(datetime.today().date())
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to explicitly cast to string type

```
today_as_string = str(date.today())
```

you can check types like this:

```
type(today)
type(today_as_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert today's date to string. The full code is this:

```
from datetime import date

choosen_asn='123456'

today = date.today()
file = open("config_" + str(today) + "_" + choosen_asn + ".txt","w+", encoding='utf-8')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime
today = datetime.today().strftime('%d%m%Y')
print(today)
```

**Output**

```
18092019
```

Answer (score 0):

You should convert date to string:

```
today = date.today()
dateStr = today.strftime("%d%m%Y")
file = open("config_" + today + "_" + choosen_asn + ".txt","w+", encoding='utf-8')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to convert date to string using str(today).